# Use mixin as variable

Tags: css, sass, mixins, node-sass, scss-mixins

I have a `@mixin` like this which I want to include it on my scss file:

```
@mixin my-gradient {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29);
}
```

And I have `$mainColor` on my Scss file which set the all colors of my project.

My question is that How I could put that `@mixin` equal to the `$mainColor` on the same file?

Comment: Are you trying to set the same `background` for `$mainColor` and in the `mixin`?

Comment: Yes, I try to set the mixin for $mainColor. On the case where the color of $mainColor will be equel to the color of mixin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can put the variable for your color right in the mixin.

```
 @mixin my-gradient {
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, $mainColor, $secondaryColor, $thirdColor);
   background: linear-gradient(to top, $mainColor, $secondaryColor, $thirdColor);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you but I try to do the opposite process( To set mixin for $mainColor )